# how to enable pager for the colored output of git diff

Tags: git, git-diff

Whenever i do git diff, it takes me to the end of the diff result.

I am using `diff3` as `diff.tool`

I want to see colored diff only for current page and it should not scrolled down until i press `j`.

When i do "core.pager" to "less",

it removed all colors and formatting, as with this image, however pagination works.

[image]

Is there exists a pager which do not alter the colors and formatting of diff result?

Comment: i don't mind the downvotes, but at least write something, or can u just tell if it is the problem with less or git pager.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `less` with `-r` or `-R` it will iterpret color codes, so creating an alias for `less` is a possible solution:

```
alias less="less -r"
```

Comment: shows "invalid option -- 'r'", in mine case `Usage: less [-EIMmNh~] [FILE]...`

Comment: Which version of less are you using?

Comment: it does not even have -v or --version, but it also shows this `BusyBox v1.23.1 (2015-09-21 10:15:59 AEST) multi-call binary.`

Comment: According to Wikipedia BusyBox provides stripped-down Unix tools. This is why you do not have the option.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative is explained with Git 2.33 (Q3 2021), where the documentation for the "`color.pager`" configuration variable has been updated.

See [commit a84216c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a84216c68435f545de38d69c771a6f2ade480394) (19 May 2021) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7ce7a61](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7ce7a617b91f14ecb005eccb38623f7fc411697b), 10 Jun 2021)</sup>

> ### [`doc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a84216c68435f545de38d69c771a6f2ade480394): explain the use of `color.pager`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> The current documentation for `color.pager` is technically correct, but slightly misleading and doesn't really clarify the purpose of the variable.
> As explained in the [original thread which added it](https://lore.kernel.org/git/E1G6zPH-00062L-Je@moooo.ath.cx/):
>
> > the point is to deal with pagers that don't understand colors.
>
> And hence it being set to "true" is necessary for colorizing output to the pager, but not sufficient by itself (you must also have enabled one of the other color options, though note that these are set to "auto" by default these days).

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a84216c68435f545de38d69c771a6f2ade480394/Documentation/config/color.txt#L130-L132):

> A boolean to specify whether `auto` color modes should colorize
> output going to the pager.
> Defaults to `true`;
>
> **Set this to `false` if your pager does not understand ANSI color codes.**

From the thread:

> > I do not really understand why you would enable color *at all* if
> > you want to disable it when paging.
> > Do you have many instances when you  want a color diff which is short enough not to be paged?
>
> When I use a pager that escapes the escape character or highlights the
> content itself the output of `git diff` without the pager should have
> colors but not with the pager.
>
> For example using `git diff` with a pathspec is quite short most of the time.
> For `git diff`, I have to enable paging manually and run `git diff | $PAGER` usually but `git log` uses the pager automatically and should not use colors with it.